# 404 after uploading file from the apache website but accessible from filemanager. Folder and file permissions are 644

Tags: php, file, yii, yii2

Website is based on Yii PHP framework. When an image is uploaded from the website (not ftp) to the folder with same kind of images, which are normally accessed by http, this image is only accessible in ftp and causes 404 error in http request.

Folder and file permissions are 755 & 644.

---

In other words, I have "*bla/foo.jpg*" and "*bla/bla.png*" which i can see by entering "*http://my.url/bla/foo.jpg*" and "*http://my.url/bla/bla.png*" or using same FTP address in *FileZilla*. Then, I upload "*girl.jpg*" from *index.html* page and it gets to the same */bla* folder.

...
And i can see bla/girl.jpg from FTP, but NOT from "*http://my.url/bla/girl.jpg*". It has the same permissions and the same address as *foo.jpg* and *bla.png* which I see from HTTP.

Files are being uploaded from html form and saved with the help of built-in Yii classes:

```
yii\web\UploadedFile;
yii\helpers\FileHelper;
yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
yii\db\ActiveRecord;

public static function upload($file, $folder, $id = null, $title = null)
{
    if ($file) {
        $path = self::createFolder($folder) . '/' .
            Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '.' .
            $file->extension;

        if ($file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@root' . $path))) {
            self::autorotateImage($file->extension, $path);

            $fileStorage = self::findOne($id);
            if ($fileStorage) {
                $fileStorage->deleteFile();
            } else {
                $fileStorage = new FileStorage();
            }
            $fileStorage->path = $path;
            $fileStorage->filename = $file->name;
            $fileStorage->title = $title;

            if ($fileStorage->validate() && $fileStorage->save()) {
                return $fileStorage->id;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here is .htaccess content:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com$
RewriteRule ^pages\/how\-it\-works$ "https\:\/\/mywebsite\.com\/pages\/how\-it\-works\/" [R=301,L]


RewriteEngine on
   # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
   # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

   #php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
   #php_value post_max_size 550M
   #php_value memory_limit 512M
   #php_value max_input_time 500
   #php_value max_execution_time 500

# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
<IfModule php7_module>
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 30
   php_value max_input_time 60
   php_value max_input_vars 1000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value post_max_size 8M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 2M
   php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

**UPD:**

tried Alon Eitan's suggestion with this mechanism, but the problem stays the same :

```
        if ($fileStorage->validate() && $fileStorage->save()) {

            $oldFolder = dirname(Yii::getAlias('@root' . $path));
            $newFolder = $oldFolder . "_new";
            mkdir($newFolder, 0755);
            self::xcopy($oldFolder, $newFolder);
            self::delete_dir($oldFolder);
            rename($newFolder, $oldFolder);

            return $fileStorage->id;
        }
```

Comment: How do you upload the image and how do you handle the uploaded file on the server? Please [edit] and include a [mcve]

Comment: edited. check it out...

Comment: whats in your `.htaccess` file and this `bla/foo.jpg` is inside the `web` accessable directory right?

Comment: yes, these files are accessible from web, except for those which uploaded through the website. Added .htaccess content to the description

Comment: @Bizley can help you out with the `.htaccess`.

Comment: @DenNikitin I had a similar problem but I can't remember how I fixed it. I think I accessed the server from FTP and renamed the images directory to `bla-old`, then created a new directory with the original name (`bla`) and moved all the files from the old directory into the new one. I don't know why this fixed the problem but I think it was something to do with resetting the owner of the directory

Comment: unfortunately, it did not help, Eitan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

Had the target folder been duplicated with .htaccess pointer on the one which did not received incoming files ¯\_(ツ)_/¯